# Matrix times vector operation with raw buffers in Eigen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, eigen

I want to replace the following generic matrix*vector function

```
void MV(double *M, double *x, double *y, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
            y[i] += M[i*m + j] * x[j];
        }
    }
}
```

with one that uses Eigen's matrix*vector operations.  This is what I have done.

```
void MV2(double *M, double *x, double *y, int n, int m)
{
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, Eigen::RowMajor> Rm;
    Eigen::Map<const Rm> Me(M, n, m);
    Eigen::Map<const Rm> xe(x, m, 1);
    Eigen::Map<Rm> ye(y, n, 1);
    ye = Me*xe;
}
```

With a simple "hello world" test (using GCC 5.3, Ubuntu 16.04) this works fine

```
int main(void)
{
  double M[12];
  double x[4];
  double y[3];
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++) M[i] = i;
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) x[i] = i;
  int n = 3, m = 4;

  MV(M,x,y,3,4);
  printf("%f %f %f\n", y[0], y[1], y[2]);
  MV2(M,x,y,3,4);
  printf("%f %f %f\n", y[0], y[1], y[2]);
}
```

However, I am now using these functions in my main application compiled with Visual Studio 2013.  I am running over many small matrices (e.g. 60x60) of various sizes from a sparse matrix composed of many small dense matrices. The `MV` function gives the correct result but the `MV2` function does not.  It's also slower. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `+=` in the MV2 version. Then, regarding performance, better let Eigen knows when you have vectors at compile time:

```
void MV2(const double *M, const double *x, double *y, int n, int m)
{
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, Eigen::RowMajor> Rm;
    Eigen::VectorXd::Map(y,n).noalias() += Rm::Map(M,n,m)
                                         * Eigen::VectorXd::Map(x,m);
}
```

The `noalias` permits to avoid a temporary by letting Eigen knows that the result can be written in `y` without aliasing issues.

**EDIT**

If `M` is symmetric, then you can tell it to Eigen as follows:

```
VectorXd::Map(y,n).noalias() += Rm::Map(M,n,m).selfadjointView<Lower>()
                              * VectorXd::Map(x,m);
```

Comment: I should probably ask this as a separate question but...my matrix is symmetric and this operations is memory bandwidth bound. Does Eigen have a optimized matrix*vector operations for symmetric matricies? This could double my throughput I think since it only has to read half the matrix.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I guess `M` still needs to be stored as the full matrix though (upper and lower triangle) though?  Can I only store the upper or lower triangle and map to that?  I will read up on this.

Comment: Actually, what I have is a symmetric sparse matrix made up of many small matrices. I optimized my code for this case like this `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { double v = M[i*m + j];  y1[i] += v*x1[j], y2[j] += v*x2[i];` and I only run over blocks in the upper triangle as well as blocks along the diagonal. I am basically applying the multiplication to the block in the upper triangle and the transpose block in the lower triangle of the sparse matrix at the same time but I only have to read the block in the upper triangle. This is measurably faster.